# California Private School Data

Tags: data-request, education, computing

Where can I find California's private school data? I'm specifically interested in exploring whether or not these schools are offering **Computer Science** education formally–and informally.

Comment: If there's some sort of accreditation process for the schools, whoever does the accreditation would likely know what courses they teach formally if they make it available as open data, I have no clue.  Also no clue on how to get the informal courses without contacting every school.

Answer (score 3):

US ED/NCES does collect data on private schools... it is called the Private School Universe Survey (PSS) but after a quick glance at the latest code book, it does not appear to have the granularity you are looking for.

https://nces.ed.gov/surveys/pss/pssdata.asp